# Wifi Direct Server/Client Connection

Tags: android, networking, wifi-direct

I am composing a WiFi Direct android app following guide of Google [Developer's guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html). I am just beginning to learn. I am stuck in sending an image from Client to Server. The following is Client and Server coding taken from Demo:

This is a code to call Client Intent (MainActivity):

```
@Override

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode ==SELECT_IMAGE) {
        Log.d(MainActivity.TAG, "onActivityResult Start");
        Log.d(MainActivity.TAG, "requestCode "+requestCode);


        Uri uri = data.getData();

        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, FileTransferService.class);
        serviceIntent.setAction(FileTransferService.ACTION_SEND_FILE);
        serviceIntent.putExtra(FileTransferService.EXTRAS_FILE_PATH, uri.toString());
        Log.d(MainActivity.TAG, "file path " + uri.toString());
        serviceIntent.putExtra(FileTransferService.EXTRAS_ADDRESS, IP_SERVER);
        serviceIntent.putExtra(FileTransferService.EXTRAS_PORT, PORT);
        this.startService(serviceIntent);
    } else {
        Log.d(MainActivity.TAG, "Service transfer failed");
    }
}
```

This is code for Client (I used IntentService in a separate class):

```
    public class FileTransferService extends IntentService {
        public static final int SOCKET_TIMEOUT = 5000;
        public static final String ACTION_SEND_FILE = "com.moon.android.wifidirectproject_moon.action.SEND_FILE";
        public static final String EXTRAS_ADDRESS = "go_host";
        public static final String EXTRAS_FILE_PATH = "file_url";
        public static final String EXTRAS_PORT = "go_port";
        Socket socket = new Socket();


        public FileTransferService() {
            super("FileTransferService");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
            Context context = getApplicationContext();

            if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_SEND_FILE)) {
                String fileUri = intent.getExtras().getString(EXTRAS_FILE_PATH);
                String host = intent.getExtras().getString(EXTRAS_ADDRESS);
                int port = intent.getExtras().getInt(EXTRAS_PORT);

                try {
                    Log.d(MainActivity.TAG, "Opening client socket - ");
                    Log.d(MainActivity.TAG, "fileUri" + fileUri);
                    Log.d(MainActivity.TAG, "host" + host);

                    socket.bind(null);
                    socket.connect((new InetSocketAddress(host, port)), SOCKET_TIMEOUT);

                    Log.d(MainActivity.TAG, "Client socket - " + socket.isConnected());
                    OutputStream stream = socket.getOutputStream();
                    ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
                    InputStream is = null;
                    try {
                        is = cr.openInputStream(Uri.parse(fileUri));
                        Log.d(MainActivity.TAG, "is - " + is);

                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        Log.d(MainActivity.TAG, e.toString());
                    }
                    copyFile(is, stream);
                    Log.d(MainActivity.TAG, "Client: Data written");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(MainActivity.TAG, e.getMessage());
                } finally {
                    if (socket != null) {
                        if (socket.isConnected()) {
                            try {
                                socket.close();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                // Give up
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public static boolean copyFile(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream out) {
            byte buf[] = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            try {
                while ((len = inputStream.read(buf)) != -1) {
                    out.write(buf, 0, len);
                }
                out.close();
                inputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d(MainActivity.TAG, e.toString());
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

This is a call to Server Intent

```
                   @Override
                    public void onConnectionInfoAvailable(WifiP2pInfo info) {



                        if (info.groupFormed && info.isGroupOwner) {

                            InetAddress groupOwnerAddress = info.groupOwnerAddress;
                            ownerIP = groupOwnerAddress.getHostAddress();
                            Log.d(MainActivity.TAG, "Owner connected" + ownerIP);
                            Intent serverIntent = new Intent(mActivity, ServerService.class);
                            serverIntent.putExtra("port",MainActivity.PORT);
                            mActivity.startService(serverIntent);
.....
```

The following is Server Intent Service:

```
public class ServerService extends IntentService {
    public static String mClientIP;

    public ServerService() {
        super("ServerService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        Integer port = intent.getExtras().getInt("port");

        try {

            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
            Socket client = serverSocket.accept();

            Log.d(MainActivity.TAG, "Server: Socket opened");
            Log.d(MainActivity.TAG, "clientIP" + client.getInetAddress().toString());
            mClientIP = client.getInetAddress().toString();
            Log.d(MainActivity.TAG, "Server: connection done");

/*
            *************I am stuck here******************************
*/
            final File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/"
                    + context.getPackageName() + "/wifip2pshared-" + System.currentTimeMillis()
                    + ".jpg");

            File dirs = new File(f.getParent());
            if (!dirs.exists())
                dirs.mkdirs();
            f.createNewFile();

            Log.d(MainActivity.TAG, "server: copying files " + f.toString());
            InputStream inputstream = client.getInputStream();
            copyFile(inputstream, new FileOutputStream(f));
            serverSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(MainActivity.TAG, e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            stopSelf();
        }
    }

    public static boolean copyFile(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream out) {
        byte buf[] = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        try {
            while ((len = inputStream.read(buf)) != -1) {
                out.write(buf, 0, len);
            }
            out.close();
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(MainActivity.TAG, e.toString());
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Lastly, the following is my LogCat. I put asterisk marks where no further progress is made in Server.

```
1) Server device (Initial State)
: search start
: WiFi_enabled
: Owner connected192.168.49.1

2) Client Device(sending image):
...............................
Opening client socket - 
: fileUricontent://media/external/images/media/16871
: host192.168.49.1
: Client socket - true
: WiFi_enabled
: is - android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$AutoCloseInputStream@3c520d34

3) Again Server Device
: Server: Socket opened
: clientIP/192.168.49.133
: Server: connection done
: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

I must confess that I don't fully understand the server/client. I just have rough knowledge. However, if you give me any hint on what I am wrong with, I will try to learn more for myself. I've spent several days working on it but couldn't work it out. Thanks for reading this post.

Comment: `************I am stuck here******`?? The code will not hang there. You get an exception? Unclear what happens. Is the directory created? Check the return value of mkdirs(). If it cannot create the directory it will return false.

Comment: You posted a very strange logcat. Better post the server logcat as is.

Comment: `open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)` Opening what? A file output stream? If that is all than posting three lines of code would have demonstrated your problem which has nothing to do with client server if it is this.